# How to add multiple custom annotation callouts rows on map in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, ios8, mapkit

**I want to add multiple rows of custom annotation callouts on MKMapkit map. Please see below screenshot, i need the scrollable rows. Currently it is not scrollable instead increasing the size of view.**

[image]

Please do help me!